# Is there any way to leave an information layer view active while switching to another tool to build?

Tags: cities-skylines

Not sure if I'm just missing something in the UI or if there's a Mod that might enable this functionality, but it seems like it would be really useful to be able to leave one of the views active while you're laying out roads / zones / districts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Persistent Resource View](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=410842044) mod does what you are looking for in part. It only works for the resource view info panel, not all of them, but it is a good start.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful.  The resource view is probably the one that needed it the most anyway.